# Width, height values are different in PhantomJS than Chrome

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am using CasperJS to crawl sites.  I have found a weird situation when parsing this site: http://socalskateshop.com/index.php?l=product_detail&p=36224

Here is the screenshot taken with CasperJS: http://prntscr.com/22rqvf

As you can see, **there is no logo**.  I dig into the DOM and I see that for that `<img>` element the width is: **384px** and the height is **10px**.

However, using Chrome I can see that the image width is **183px** and the height **100px**.  So my question is... What happened with the image itself with CasperJS? I see that the protocol of the src is **https**, but would that affect at all?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML for that image is broken: there is an extra quote mark at the end:

```
<img src="https://socalskateshop.com/themes/classic_black/images/socalskateshoplogoH.jpg"" alt=... />
                                                                                        ^^
```

My guess is that Chrome started being more tolerant of HTML mistakes at some point. (Remember PhantomJS is roughly equivalent to Chrome 13 or Safari 5.1)

Unfortunately, assuming you don't run that site and cannot fix the HTML, I cannot think of a good workaround. Some ideas are switch to using SlimerJS, or run a proxy server between that checks for and fixes bad HTML.